# Positioning background image after text

Tags: css

I want to make as this **[background img][text][background img2]**

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<table border:0>
   <tr>
        <td><span class="img-left"></span><span class="text-img">My Text is here</span><span class="img-right"></span></td>
        <td><span class="img-left"></span><span class="text-img">My Text2 is here</span><span class="img-right"></span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.img-left{
    background: transparent url('left-img.PNG') left center no-repeat;
    width:23px; 
    height:24px; 
    position:relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
.img-right{
    background: transparent url('right-img.PNG') right center no-repeat;
    width:23px; 
    height:24px; 
    position:relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
.text-img{
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 23px;
}
```

The result : **[img1&2][text]** but I want **[img1][text][img2]**

Anyone help?

Comment: How come you aren't just using an <img> tag to represent the images?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast : if I use <img> tag, the text will be bottom, and image upper,,, i have try use vertical-align middle but fail because the this code use wysywig editor,,, so the conclusion use background image

Comment: Hey, check this out.. I may have solved your image issue! Let me know if this works! http://jsfiddle.net/GCbGs/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just the `td` and `.text-img` elements by putting the backgrounds on them. Using 'padding-left`and`padding-right` on the two elements will push the text to prevent overlapping: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wUHx2/)**

Using `right` instead `left` on the right image will force it to the right side of the element.